# Adding React via Script Tags

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

When I add React via script tags (as described [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)), and also add Babel as script tag, I can write a script tag like this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This works. However, creating a new JavaScript file with this exact content and adding a script tag with the path to it as its src attribute does not. I'm a complete beginner, this is propably a really simple problem, but please help me out. Why does this not work, and how can I make it work?

Edit: This is how my files look:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// index.js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: "script tag with the path to it as its src attribute does not" — What does the script tag look like? What does the rest of the HTML look like? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Have you done anything to identify the cause of the error? Such as look at the Console in the browser's developer tools? Are there any reports there?

Comment: @Quentin I added what you requested. I thought it would be clear without it, but you're right, this is better.

Comment: That code works when I test it. I suspected it might be a CORS problem, but since you haven't said the Console showed an error…

Comment: Do you use a local web server or do you simply open the html file in a web browser? You need a web server when referencing other files, so I also suspect a CORS problem.